# why if $a \text{ mod } p = -1$ then $a \text{ mod } p = p-1$

Tags: number-theory, modules

This seems very simple and obvious but I can't prove it. why if $a \text{ mod } p = -1$ then $a \text{ mod } p = p-1$?

thank you.

Comment: $-1$ an $p-1$ are in the same residue class modulo $p$

Comment: -1 and p - 1 belongs to the same equivalence class

Comment: @Peter I almost know nothing about number theory. what does it mean? I know it is true. but I can't explain

Comment: Where did you see this? The way (some) CompSci people use the mod operator, this is strictly speaking not true. For they use $a\bmod p$ to denote the remainder (between $0$ and $p-1$) when $a$ is divided by $p$.

Comment: essentially because $p$ is congruent to zero modulo $p$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas You are right, I am working on a randomized algorithm (generating a randomized algorithm to see if a number is prime or not), and I need to prove the correctness of this (though I know it is true).

Comment: @Drupalist: What they mean (though the notation is not quite right) is that $p-1$ and $-1$ differ by a multiple of $p$ (indeed by $p$) so they can be treated effectively as being "the same" (modulo $p$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $a \text{ mod } p = -1$, you already know that $p| a+1$.

Since $p|-p$, you can infer $p| ( a+1)+(-p)$ and $p| a-(p-1)$, that is to say $a \text{ mod } p = p-1$.

Comment: Thank you. How did you find out that if $a \text{ mod } p = -1$ then $p|(a+1)$? (sorry if it looks silly!)

Comment: In high school I was taught that $a \text{ mod } p = b \iff p| (a-b)$. What's your definition of $ \text{ mod }$ exactly ?

Comment: I read the same thing, but I can't use these things in the proofs !

Answer (score 1):

if $ a \equiv -1\ (\textrm{mod}\ p)$, 
then $a \equiv (- 1) + n * p, \ \forall n \in Z$.

Let $n = 1$, then $a \equiv -1 + 1 * p$, Hence $a \equiv p - 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$a \bmod p$ is the only integer $r$ such that $a \equiv r \bmod p$ and $0 \le r \le p-1$.

Therefore, if $a \equiv -1 \bmod p$, then $a \bmod p = p - 1$, because $p-1 \equiv -1 \equiv a \bmod p$ and $0 \le p-1 \le p-1$.